# How to set a directory in PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pkg-config, pocketsphinx

I want to add a directory containing a .pc file, to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable, that is required for a certain program to run on Ubuntu. I tried to find out a solution from google but it didn't really work.

I am pasting the log here. Please help.

```
tasbeer@tasbeer-desktop:~/Android/pocketsphinx/swig$ make
cc -g -Wall -DPIC -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include `pkg-config
--cflags sphinxbase pocketsphinx`  -c -o pocketsphinx_wrap.o
pocketsphinx_wrap.c
**Package sphinxbase was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sphinxbase.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sphinxbase' found
Package pocketsphinx was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pocketsphinx.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'pocketsphinx' found**
```

Comment: What solution did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the path maybe a bit of a red herring.

I had a similar issue (while installing a different package). I solved that particular issue by downloading a latest project tar from the project website (linkparser in this case) and installing following the instructions included.

This thread kind of helped me in the right direction:

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/suse-linux/87624-adjusting-pkg_config_path-environment-variable.html